# How to change .webloc file icon?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, icon, desktop

Chrome is my default web browser.

Sometimes, I drag URLs from the Chrome address bar to the desktop.

When I do this, they always take the Safari "webloc" icon.

How can I pick another icon, like Chrome?

I'd like to do this for ALL such webloc files. I'm aware that, by turning on file extensions and deleting a single file's "webloc", this could be done. But I'd like it to be the case across the board.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Change the application which opens .webloc (web location/link files)

1. In the Finder select the file.
2. Menu > File > Get Info (shortcut `⌘ I`)
3. The file info window opens
4. In the section "Open with" change from "Safari" to "Chrome" or whatever other application.
5. You now have effectively changed the file type association.
6. What you did here is "changing the handler application".
7. There are handlers for

   - particular file types

     - most commonly identified from the file extension, e.g. `.txt`, `.jpg` or `.webloc` in our example
   - or protocols (like `http://`, `https://` or `mailto://`)
   - or on iOS and Android and modern macOS and Windows also handlers for URLs, so that every address starting with a certain domain name to be opened not in the generic browser but in the optimized app.

### Changing the Icon

On macOS there are these fundamental ways which determine which icon is shown for a file.

1. If you are in Icon View (Menu > View > As Icons`⌘ 1`) or in List View (Menu > View > As List `⌘ 2`) with "Show Icon preview" activated, then the Finder shows a thumbnail of the actual file content (text, image, spreadsheet, whatever it is).
2. If you don't have icon preview, then you get:
   a) a generic file type specific icon, which gives an abstract idea on the content type.
   b) a custom arbitrary icons which you can assign to any file or folder on macOS.

Note:

- Changing the handler app as described in the first section, may change the generic icon for that file type, if the handler app provides an icon for that particular file type or provides a generic fallback icon.
- In addition to that the Mac also offers to give each file or folder an arbitrary icon.

  - In the "File Info" window mentioned above, simply select the icon on the top, then paste an image from your clipboard.
  - To clear that, select the icon in that dialog again and press the backspace button.

    - It then falls back to the generic icon of that file type or to the generic folder icon.